# Labeling outside polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling

is it possible to place a label automatically outside its polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234038/in-qgis-how-do-you-place-horizontal-label-outside-polygon-border/234073#234073) resolving this issue

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In Layer properties, you can use Labels -> Placement -> Using perimeter. You can choose Position as 'Below line' and adjust the Distance to achieve something like below.[image: labels outside polygon]

Comment: perimeter is not necessarily outside the polygon.

Comment: Modified answer to show specific options that may help.